# google maps into circular div

Tags: javascript, html, google-maps

I need to put a google maps into a div and this one must be a circular div, but I've two problem

1. at load time I see standard rectangular div and after half second this div became circular
2. when use this map in *draggable* way I see always a standard div and only after mouse leave I see circle again

Comment: Please read this http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0):

I think that the main idea is the order of loading files in your site: html, css, js.
Take a look at this: http://jsfiddle.net/nfng1sm4/
. You only have to change the background color in to the color of your container div.

```
 .circle-text, #googleMap {
width: 500px;
height: 380px;
-moz-border-radius: 50%;
-webkit-border-radius: 50%;
border-radius: 50%;
background: #4679BD;}
```

Answer (score 0):

adding css `position: relative;`, `z-index:` and `border-radius` to the parent div of the map holder, it will mask the child div(#mapCanvas)

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/deep3015/hnadgbma/1/) demo

css

```
.mapCover {
  position: relative;
  width: 300px;
  height: 300px;
  border: 5px solid #000000;
  border-radius: 400px;
  overflow: hidden;
  z-index: 1000;
}

#mapCanvas {
  width: 300px;
  height: 300px;
}
```

html

```
  <div class="mapCover">
    <div id="mapCanvas"></div>
  </div>
```